# One to Many relation: How to refer multiple column?

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I'm sorry because my question maybe not clearly.But I want to create a notification table for user.
notify table have 2 column, one for user who send notify and one for user who receive this notify.

The notify table like this

```
@Entity('notify')
export class Notify{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    notifyId:string;


    @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.notifies)
    receiver: User

    @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.notifies)
    sender: User
    
}
```

But in other side, I dont know how to create user table.

I think it like that.But at OneToMany decoration, should I refer to receiver or sender?

```
@Entity('user')
export class User{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id:number;

    ...

    @OneToMany(() => Notify, (notify) => notify.receiver,{nullable:true})
    notifies?: Notify[]
   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the **JoinColumn** decorator from TypeORM to maintain the segregation between the relations.

```
 @OneToMany(() => Notify, (notify) => notify.sender,{nullable:true})
 @JoinColumn({ name: 'sender' })
 notifies?: Notify[]


 @OneToMany(() => Notify, (notify) => notify.receiver,{nullable:true})
 @JoinColumn({ name: 'receiver' })
 notifies?: Notify[]
```